# axis label text rotation

Tags: plotting

I've got the following script:

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]];

h[x_, n_] := (x - 1/\[Theta])/(1 + \[Theta])^n + 1/\[Theta];
trap[m_, n_] := Clip[{
    {If[n == 0, 0, h[a, m - n]], h[a, m]}, {h[a, m - n - 1], 
     h[a, m]},
    {h[a, m - n], h[a, m + 1]}, {If[n == 0, 0, h[a, m - n + 1]], 
     h[a, m + 1]}
    }, {0, a}];

isinty[y_, n_] := h[a, n + 1] <= y <= h[a, n];
isintx[x_, y_, n_] := 0 <= x <= g[y, n];

labela = ToString[Subscript[h, 0], StandardForm] <> "(A)=A ";
labela = "A";
gr := Append[Append[Table[h[a, n], {n, 0, nmax}], 0], 1/\[Theta]];
grlabels :=
  Append[
   Append[
    Append[
     Prepend[
      Table[{h[a, n], 
        Style[ToString[Subscript[h, n], StandardForm] <> "(A) ", 
         Black]}, {n, 1, nmaxlabels}], {a, Style[labela, Black]}],
     {0, Style["0", Black]}],
    {1/\[Theta], 
     Style["\!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(\[Theta]\)]\)", Black]}],
   {h[a, 5], Style["...", Black]}];

line := Plot[x, {x, 0, a},
   PlotRange -> {{0, a}, {0, a}},
   PlotStyle -> {Gray, Thin, Dotted}];


arrx := Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.05], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, a}}]}];
arry := Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.05], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {a, 0}}]}];


\[Theta] = 7/10;
a = 20;
nmax = 5;
nmaxlabels = 3;
trapindex = <|row -> 3, column -> 1|>;
isbw = True;

Show[Flatten[{line, arrx, arry}],
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
 PlotRangeClipping -> False,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameStyle -> 
  Directive[LineColor -> Transparent, FontFamily -> "Courier", 
   FontSize -> 15.0],
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Black], Style["y", Black]},
 FrameTicks -> {grlabels, grlabels},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 ImageSize -> {800, 800}]
```

It produces the following figure:
[image: Output]

I would like to rotate by 90 degrees the three dots appearing right above the label $1/\theta$ on the $y$-axis, and do the same for the second $y$-axis which is on the right of the plot.

How do I do this rotation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FrameTicks -> {grlabels, grlabels /. "..." :> Rotate["...", Pi/2]}

Comment: `Rotate[Text[Style["...", Black]], \[Pi]/2]`  By the way, this problem could have been posed with one line of code (30 characters or so).

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, that's good enough.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thanks. I agree I should have trimmed the code a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For use as tick labels, it may be more compact to use special characters:

```
Style["\[CenterEllipsis]", Black]
```

> $\cdots$

```
Style["\[VerticalEllipsis]", Black]
```

> $\vdots$